# Replace the index screen with a custom HTML page on a Joomla website

Tags: joomla

I will start by saying that I have basically no experience using Joomla or even really PHP. I wish to set a temporary "new site coming soon" html page as the index screen for the website (a joomla php site at moment but will not be in the near future).

When i checked out the website files I was a little disturbed as there is no index.php/index.html located in the website root directory. I am not sure how exactly the Joomla CMS works (and not to keen to get into it to be honest) but really need to get this temp screen up... any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have an `index.php` file in the root folder of your installation, you have an incomplete copy of Joomla. However, if your webserver is Apache, `index.html` usually takes precedence over `index.php`. You should just be able to upload your own `index.html` to the root folder for a temporary page.

Answer (score 0):

The `index.php` you're looking for is in the templates folder, knowing what templates you're using, go to `\joomla\templates\template_name` and edit `index.php` there.

Comment: cheers for the response - definitly good to know, however i think i may have an incomplete joomla on my hands, not such file exists in the location!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest the jlleblanc method.

Otherwise you could write an article and post the "coming soon" into it, then publish on the main menu as the default menu item and delete all the other content. This way you'll use the Joomla template.

Comment: cheers for the response - went for the jlleblanc method as suggested. I read about that option on a joomla forum, seemed a bit much though :S. Still good to know.